Upper bound on LCM of an arithmetic progression
Let $a$ be an even integer. I want to find a good upper bound on the least common multiple $L(a)$ of all elements in the set $\{a-1, 2a-1, 3a-1, \ldots, 2a^2-1\}$. A somewhat trivial bound can be obtained by taking the product:
\begin{align*}
L(a) &\le \prod_{i = 1}^{2a} (ia - 1) \\
&< \prod_{i = 1}^{2a} ia \\
&= a^{2a}(2a)!
\end{align*}
Written differently, this gives us $L(a) < e^{ca \log(a)}$ for some $c$. But I would like to do better than $L(a) < e^{ca \log(a)}$. Ideally something like $e^{ca}$ for some constant $c$. If such a bound is not even true, then that would be helpful information as well.
If it helps, even a proof or reference to a bound like $\displaystyle \inf_{x < a < 2a} L(a) < e^{ca}$ could be useful, where the infimum is taken over all even $a$ in some large interval.
I did find a paper on this issue here, but it does not seem strong enough for my purposes.
